# How to post links with the twitter API?

Tags: api, rest, twitter

I'm using the twitter API, but when I post links they are showing up as text and not links. I haven't been able to find the documentation showing how to post a link that actually works.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't keep the prefix (http://) and just post something like www.google.com, the link won't be picked up.

Comment: I'll point out that the URL has to have a basic `domain`+`TLD` format to be recognized as a link. For instance, in testing I found that `http://localhost/` URLs don't get turned into links. But if they look like `http://foo.bar/`, they link (even if the domain is bogus).

Comment: Seems they don't like *any* localhost-like URLs. Racking my brains why my URLs weren't being parsed; switched it from 127.0.0.1 to another domain and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL contains special characters you need encode it before posting to Twitter so it will be converted to a link:

```
from urllib import quote
url = quote(url)
```