# twitter php statuses/update

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using [this php library](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) to post a tweet. How to post a link, so it appears as a proper link?

When I use urlencode, I get this result http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fnew_poedu%2Fdefault%2Fride%2Fview%2F18. If I don't use it the result is `http://localhost/new_poedu/default/ride/view/13`, just simple text not link.

Comment: Twitter doesn't store links in tweets, do they? It's up to the script displaying the tweets to parse the tweet for links and replace them as such.

Comment: @MetalFrog: Twitter _might_ convert text to links when rendering, I'm not sure.  Though if they do then something like `localhost` in the example here may not make it through that process.  It might get filtered out as potentially malicious by Twitter's link-generating code.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to tweet a link, I just copied from url bar and pasted it, but I did it via twitter site interface. But using php library and just putting there link is not working properly, as I mentioned it appears as merely text not link.... David, maybe you're right about localhost, I'll try it. Thank you

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957033/how-to-post-links-with-the-twitter-api